# Xamarin.Android Inflate a custom view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-custom-view, custom-view

Another day with Xamarin.

Well, let me clear this out first-hand : *I am new to android development as well as to Xamarin*

So, I am trying to create a custom `View` in my project and trying to set(or `inflate`) it's view from a layout. I have created a layout and trying to inflate it from the `View`.

**CustomLayout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff">
   <EditText android:layout_height="120dp"
   android:layout_width="120dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Customlayout.cs**

```
public class Customlayout : LinearLayout
{
    public Customlayout(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        Inin();
    }
    public Customlayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Inin();
    }

    public Customlayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        Inin();
    }
    private void Inin()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomLayout, this, true);
        this.AddView(view);
    }
}
```

The code doesn't have any affect on the view. When I reference it in any other layout, it stays blank. I know my code isn't correct, I just tried this code after going through tons of Java and android related questions. I am not even sure if this is the way to go.

Any ideas on how I can inflate the view?

Comment: It seems you are making it complicate.You can use `Customlayout` instead of `LinearLayout`  in the `xml` and can get rid of the `AddView` part in `Customlayout`.

Comment: @sunilsunny, so you mean i should inherit from a `CustomLayout`? And how would i get rid of `AddView`? (I tried inheriting from `CustomLayout` but not sure which assembly contains it. Which one should i reference?)

Comment: I will add it as a answer just give it a try.

Comment: @sunilsunny, sure! I'm waiting for it.

Comment: does it work now ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Yes, it works perfectly. Not sure why but there was an accepted answer but it seems to be removed now. Anyways, i will mark yours as the accepted one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it works for me like this :

in **Customlayout.cs** change `Init()` like this:

```
private void Init()
  {  
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
   View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.customlayout, null, true);
   this.AddView(view);
  }
```

then in your **activity layout.axml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <namespace.CustomLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Customlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp" />
    </Customlayout>
```

You have to give the correct package name .It will look something like this `your_packageName.Customlayout`

```
public class Customlayout : LinearLayout
{
    public Customlayout(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        Inin();
    }
    public Customlayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Inin();
    }

    public Customlayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        Inin();
    }
    private void Inin()
    {

    }
}
```

Load `CustomLayout.axml` in your `Fragment` or `Activity` like you normally do.

Comment: Not working. Tried it and now the view is just a gray background with the class-name in the middle!

Comment: You saw that on the preview screen right ?. Try running on the device.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Which means when i use `mynamespace.CustomLayout` in the `CustomLayout.axml` file, it goes blank - which means the designer fails.

Comment: Designer usually fails but if you run it on device it should work.

Comment: Tried it... App just crashed in the emulator without any exception.

Comment: By the way, the namespace has to be all in lower-case, right?

Comment: Namespace should be the exact same.

Comment: I can now run the app, but result is the same. It's still blank.

Comment: Screen is white? or still black?. If it's white, it's working. Try clicking the editext.

Comment: I am putting this inside my main activity : `<TestApp.CustomLayout
     android:layout_height="150dp"
     android:layout_width="150dp"/>` But even in the emulator, it's just blank. I even set the `EditText`'s background to `Black` but nothing is seen on screen.

Comment: One thing i don't understand. Where is the relation between the xml file and the code-behind `.cs` file?